# svelte: importing store from a component?

Tags: svelte, sveltekit, svelte-component, svelte-store

I have created a readable store in a svelte component (`src/components/myComponent.svelte`) like so

```js
import { readable } from "svelte/store";

export let data;

const mags = data.magazines;
export const allMags = readable(mags);

console.log($allMags) // correct output
```

I want to import this store into my `src/store.js` file so that I can use it to create derived stores. I have tried the following:

```js
import { writable, readable, derived } from "svelte/store";
import { allMags } from "../src/components/myComponent.svelte";
// console.log($allMags)
```

I have encountered the following errors:

> client.ts:112 SyntaxError: The requested module '/src/components/myComponent.svelte?t=1696086887675' does not provide an export named 'allMags' (at stores.js?t=1696086887675:2:10)

Obviously, logging $allMags didn't work and I received this error:

```
|- ReferenceError: $allMags is not defined  
   at eval (src/stores.js:8:13)  
   at async instantiateModule (/node_modules/vite/dist/node/chunks/dep-e8f070e8.js:54405:9)

Internal server error: $allMags is not defined
```

I think (I am a svelte noob) the issue is originating in the import of `allMags` in the `store.js` file. Is this not allowed? If it is allowed, how can I fix the import statement?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You cannot import a store from a component unless it is exported from the [`context="module"` script](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-context-module). Any other export is a property on a *component instance*.
2. Even if you do that, you cannot use [`$store` syntax](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-components#script-4-prefix-stores-with-$-to-access-their-values) outside of Svelte files. To get the store value once, use the [`get` utility function](https://svelte.dev/docs/svelte-store#get). To continually receive store change notifications, use the `subscribe` function on the store itself.